# dockerのコマンドが見つからない

Tags: linux, docker

#### 前提・実現したいこと

Linuxで"sudo apt install docker"でインストールしたものの「dokcer」のコマンドが見つからない
Linuxでdockerを使う方法を教えてください。
また、この問題がPATHの問題ならば、どこのフォルダに入っていたか教えてほしいです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
bash: docker: コマンドが見つかりません
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
$ docker
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

- MX Linux

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/260059

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しました

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

これから先はDocker CLIコマンドが必要らしいです。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61693307/i-cant-find-the-docker-command/61693343#61693343